# Can an array be specified in an ini file to be parsed using Zend_Config_Ini

Tags: zend-framework

Is there a way to specify a one dimensional array in a ini file.

so in my ini I would like to do

someproperty = [array of something]

I am using `Zend_Config_Ini` config adapter (I prefer ini for base configuration).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
someproperty[] = a
someproperty[] = b
someproperty[] = c
someproperty[] = d
someproperty[] = e
```

see: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php#75983

Comment: And is it possible to do it for multi dimensional (so someproperty values maybe a hash/multidimensional array) ?

Comment: I came across an issue today where this syntax will not work correctly if a [section] is not defined at the top of the ini file.

Not sure if this is a bug, but definitely worth noting!

Comment: @Tom: thanks for pointing it out, gave me a hard time - I'd definitely consider this a bug!

Answer (score 7):

Although undocumented, this seems to work quite well too:

```
foo[bar] = 5
foo[baz] = 6
hello[world] = 7
```

Comment: This works for me too. You'll have to do `$config->get('the_key')->toArray()` to use it as an array in PHP.

Comment: It's no longer undocumented.  Arrays with empty indices and string indices are covered in the examples for `parse_ini_file()`.  See: http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Answer (score 6):

You can use separators to make further sub-sections, and they are presented as either another level of objects ($config->some->a) or with $config->toArray(), they can be turned into a multi-level array.

Combining both the above techniques to make arrays, and the separators like so:

```
some.a[] = a
some.a[] = b
some.b[] = c
```

will give the results you are looking for.

```
array('some' => array('a' => array(0 => 'a',
                                   1 => 'b'),
                      'b' => array(0 => 'c')
                     ));
```

Comment: The dotted syntax won't work for PHP's build in `parse-ini-file`-function. The square-bracket-syntax will only work for one-dimensional arrays.